# Recovering virtual machine from increasing disk size

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, filesystems, vdi

I lacked free space on my VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 desktop virtual machine, so I desided to just go to VirtualBox client settings and resize VDI from 32 to 50 GB. After that the machine doensn't boot: it starts loading for a minute and then there's just blank screen with cursor. I freed enough space for VDI extension, so the problem must be somewhere else.

I found this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286735/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-virtualbox-vdi-resize-to-get-more-disk-space , and looks like I have the same problem: expanded the drive but left filesystem unchanged. However, I'm not sure about the solution:

```
Boot Ubuntu with Live CD
Open Disks App
Click on Paritions shows up on the screen
Options -> resize option -> fill max available size
Options -> Repair File System
```

Seems like booting with Live CD will erase all important data and rollback the machine to defaults. Plus my Internet is not very fast, so it will take time to download the .iso file this solution requires.

Am I right in my conserns that this method won't work in my case? If so, how can I recover the machine and repare all this mess?

Comment: The method should work. It's the same as in a bare metal installation. You're only booting a live session, not reinstalling Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting with a Linux Live CD will not erase anything, if you do nothing dangerous
to the disk.
You should use the live CD for running the `disks` app, not for installing Linux again
(which will erase lots of stuff).

The procedure that you outlined should work.